# Is there cloud functions that trigger if database changes and send notification to users subscriber to 'topics'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am working in an android app project for my college minor project. Everything is working but now i want to add a notification feature, i.e whenever a admin posts a notice every user subscriber to that topic gets notification, i tried to follow different tutorials and documents but since i have no programming background in js/nodejs/php i couldn't understand the cloud functions.
Can anyone write the functions or lead me to the answer?

i want the function to be triggered when a new notice is added inside /Notice and send notification to all users subscribe to Notice..

i wrote the following code, after some study,

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotices = 
functions.database.ref('/Notices/{nID}').onCreate((event) => {const data = 
event.data;
if(!data.changed()){
    console.log('Nothing changed');
    return;
}else{
    console.log(data.val());
}

const payLoad = {
    notification:{
        title: 'Message received',
        body: 'You received a new message',
        sound: "default"
    }
};

const options = {
    priority: "high",
    timeToLive: 60*60*2
};

return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("bctb", payLoad, options);});
```

and got the error in console of firebase,what am i doing wrong here,
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'changed' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotices.functions.database.ref.onCreate 
    (/user_code/index.js:8:13)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
    functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
    at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud- 
    functions.js:135:20)
    at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:770:24
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)

Comment: The whole idea of Cloud Functions is that you can create such functionality yourself. If you are new to JavaScript, Cloud Functions for Firebase is not the best way to learn it. I recommend first reading the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and/or taking the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not familiar with the Firebase Cloud Functions, I recommend you first go through official docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAvqDiBRDAARIsADWh5Tf5344EGjtp8HMVpsZgEmg_dz-0Po34glXNpvdytgoP5x8gbWNfcPIaAkjqEALw_wcB), because without going through the basics you won't understand how they work and then go through Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAvqDiBRDAARIsADWh5TfqjNiFJMVur2iTUb4Q3OAZGdkSFg1t3b8ibTuZ-DCVkp7TydWKoKsaAsa2EALw_wcB). Once you get to know how both the service work it'll be a lot easier for you to understand and write your own cloud function. For your ease here is how your function should be like.

You can do this by simply creating an `onCreate` trigger function. So it will look something like:

```
exports.SendNotification = functions.database.ref('/Notice/{nid}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    //Your notification code here
 }
```

Here `nid` is the notice id that is just created. `Firebase` will automatically get this id. And for sending the notification you can use Firebase cloud messaging (FCM). In this cloud function you can create a notification payload.

```
//send notification 
    const payload = {
      data:{
        title: "New notice has been added!",
     }
};
```

Now you can send this notification to the app using:

```
admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instID, payload);
```

Here, `instID` is the instance ID. Each app installed has a unique instance ID. For sending to multiple devices you'll have to wrap the code line above in an loop to send notifications to all of the subscribed users. For this you need instance IDs of all the subscribed users.

"I hear and I forget, I see and I remember, I do and I understand"

Best of luck.

Comment: Hey, so i read the documentations, saw some examples on cloud functions and with your code as reference i wrote the following code,

Comment: there was typo mistake in code ie  instead of "something" i wrote, 'something'. Thanks for the help :)